# How to convert string into a variable in php

Tags: php, variables, programming-languages

In PHP I am creating a table where I have inserted an input box and it is named as `A,B,C,D,E,.....,Z (Caps)`.

Now I have to fetch the data inserted in that particular input box. Is there any way I can convert string A,B,C,D,E.... into a variable?

Keep in mind the data inserted into the input box should be fetched.

Comment: you mean, you named your input box like `name='A'` and then you put the value to that input?

Comment: This question is Unclear and missing vital details.

Comment: Edit your question.  Show us some code.  Show us what you are working toward.  It sounds like you might want to hardcode some subarrays with alphabetical keys into a superglobal array... but I can't (nor can anyone else) confidently answer the question as it is currently posted.

Comment: You really have something like `<input type="text" name="A,B,C,D,E,...Z" ... />` in your code?!

Comment: Do you need `$_GET["A"] in A,B,C,D,E,.....,XSS HOLEZ (Caps)`

Comment: @Akshansh please update your question so that we can offer an accurate / correct solution for your task.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is the question, you can surely use `$_REQUEST["whatever"]`.

This is perfect for you at this stage, as data are always available with it, no matter the scope

In most cases, it is also **very bad** for security, as it allow special crafted [xss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), [session cookie hijacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking), [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and more fun stuffs.

From ***my view***, it is very good to play with it **now**, and see what are the differences with `$_GET`, or `$_POST`.

> $_REQUEST This is a 'superglobal', or automatic global, variable. This
>   simply means that it is available in all scopes throughout a script.
>   There is no need to do global $variable; to access it within functions
>   or methods.
>
> The variables in $_REQUEST are provided to the script via the GET,
>   POST, and COOKIE input mechanisms and therefore could be modified by
>   the remote user and **cannot be trusted**.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php